# PHP mod_rewrite Anchors

Tags: php, jquery, apache, mod-rewrite, anchor

I have mod_rewrite working with all my urls.

But I have some anchor links, such as Back to Top referencing #top.

I also have a jquery slider with a start stop button. This button uses a href="#" to trigger, but this is not starting or stopping the slider, instead it reloads the page. And therefore the slider goes back to slide 1 with the slider playing.

Any ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `mod_rewrite`, your problem lies on the jQuery slider script. Fix that, or show it to us so we can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

mod_rewrite has nothing to do with it. You need need prevent the default functionality of an A link.

Something in the lines of:

```
$('a.slidertrigger').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I just removed the href="#" and left the <a id="slider-stopper"> and that button was still functioning ok.

Comment: Umm. Not ideal. You should fix your script to prevent the default click handler being applied. Not to mention browsers without JS...